# How to give external developers access to AWS (aws-sdk-v1-1.67.0)

Tags: amazon-web-services

My app is using AWS (aws-sdk-v1-1.67.0) to hit SimpleDB. I am having some external developers do some work. I am trying to setup an IAM Role so they don't have my secret production keys.

Going through the list of IAM Group roles there isn't one for SimpleDB. Does anyone have a clue on how to get this is working?

Comment: what happens when you try to create your own role, select the options (read, write etc) and assign it to your simpleDB via its ARN?

Comment: Have you tried defining custom role with the policies related to SimpleDB? Define one and have the external developers assume that role to get access.

Answer (score 0):

Consumer (such as user/devs or application) need a Role.
Resource (such as simple DB) need a policy.
You attach a policy to the role and thats how you control access.

You can do the following

> 1. Create a new role for external devs.
> 2. Define custom policy for Simple DB. See link below.
> 3. Attach this new policy to the role you created.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingIAMWithSDB.html

Also check how to use assumed role in your use case.

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html